# Caption Justification

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I know that is has been asked several times. But I think my problem is a bit different. I want to make my figure captions left aligned and justified. I don't want all of them to be like this because I have subfigures for them I want centered caption.

`\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}` is working but the text is not justified and `\captionsetup{justification=justified}` gives me a centered caption! I am using TeXstudio.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal, but working example (MWE).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happened. Did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand well what you want,

```
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
```

should do it.

However, note the caption will begin at the text left margin, not at the left side of the figure, which will be ugly for small figures.

Two  packages allow to have a caption width equal to the figure width:

- `measuredfigure`, an environment defined by the `threeparttable` package.
- `floatrow` defines a `\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{...}\label{...}}{figure commands}` to be inserted in a `figure` environment.
  If necessary, you can have a caption width different from the figure width, changing the optional argument to, say, `[0.25\textwidth]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, \captionsetup[figure]{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off} makes the caption centered for my document! I don't know why! This is getting very frustrating! I am using revtex4-1. Any comment on this?

Comment: Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: I wanted to attach some photos but I didn't know how. Here is an example. This gives the caption centered.

\begin{figure}[htbp]

\begin{center}

\captionsetup[figure]{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-22pt}

\includegraphics[width=3 in]{SchematicHB.jpg}

\caption{Exerted force of the nonzero ... }

\label{Fig:SchematicHB}

\end{center}

\end{figure}

Comment: You should edit our question, and post a full compilable short code, rather than a snipet in a comment.